# При вызове deven.exe /log вылетает ошибка

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Добрый день.

При вызове deven.exe /log вылетает ошибка. Собственно, такая ошибка вылетает всегда при запуске ярлыка VS2013. Подскажите, в чем может быть дело.

Имя события проблемы: BEX

Имя приложения: devenv.exe

Версия приложения: 12.0.21005.1

Отметка времени приложения: 524fcb34

Имя модуля с ошибкой: StackHash_5861

Версия модуля с ошибкой: 0.0.0.0

Отметка времени модуля с ошибкой: 00000000

Смещение исключения: PCH_A9_FROM_ntdll+0x0003AAAC

Код исключения: c0000005

Данные исключения: 00000008

Версия ОС: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.16.7

Код языка: 1049

Дополнительные сведения 1: 5861

Дополнительные сведения 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2

Дополнительные сведения 3: 84a0

Дополнительные сведения 4: 84a09ea102a12ee665c500221db8c9d

**Обновление**

Вижу проблему в том, что не могу запустить VS2013 - выпадается ошибка. Хотел сохранить лог запуска приложения, так даже это не дает сделать из-за ошибки. Воспроизвести проблему легко -достаточно нажать на ярлык VS2013 или запустить devenv.exe.

Comment: @Mansso, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Необходима еще информация?

Comment: Вот тут решили похожую проблему http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407777/visual-studio-2010-crashes-repeatedly

Comment: Спасибо,почитал..не то..